# Auto Increment Only Specific Features?

Tags: qgis, qfield, geology, autoincrement

I'm using QField to collect geologic data in the Outback.

I'm creating point data, with various fields for rock type etc.

Occasionally I take samples of the rocks, and want a field that auto-increments the sample number. The problem I have is that most entries do not require a sample, so a simple '$rownumber' query is not suitable.

What I'm picturing is a field for "sample_taken?"   'Y'/'N', and if 'Y' then an auto-incremented number is inserted continuing from the last sample number I used. For example:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can try using something like the expression below as a default value for your `Sample Number` field in QGIS ([see docs](https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/vector-layers.html#default-values) for info on default values)

But do *not* enable 'Apply default value on update' as you don't want your sample numbers to change if you go back and modify some other feature in the record.

I assume here you want to retain the text format with zero-padding of the numbers.

```
CASE WHEN "sample_taken" = 'Y'
THEN 
lpad(maximum(to_int(coalesce("sample_no",0)))+1,4,'0')
ELSE 
NULL
END
```

However you may not see this work properly in QField as there seems to be a limitation on default values being created on insert when they rely on a value from another field in the feature being digitised (see [issue #914](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/914) on GithHub)

---

If you encounter the above issue, one workaround for your case could be to collect your sample records on another layer.

Either create a separate file altogether, or duplicate the original layer reference in the layer panel (i.e., two references to the same file), with the original filtered to `"sample_taken" = 'N'` (Non-sample layer) and the other filtered to `"sample_taken" = 'Y'` (Sample layer).

Then set up the default value for `Sample Number`, but only for the Sample layer, using just the third line in the above expression (so there is no reference to `"sample_taken"`).

When you are digitising in the field and you know you'll collect a sample, you need to switch to editing the Sample layer and then input your data; the `Sample Number` should then autoincrement only within its own layer, without looking at records from the Non-sample layer (i.e. records where `"sample_taken" = 'N'`)